# How Can i display the output of MySQL “PRINT” Command in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a mysql stored procedure using c# asp net.

This stored procedure tried in mysql works fine.

Instead tested on code behind of my project I have mysql syntax error.

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-8.0.12]You have an error
> in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysp' at line 1

How to extract the output of "PRINT" Command i.e the procedure in C# how can i do that ?

**.cs**

```
using (OdbcConnection cn =
  new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (OdbcCommand command =
        new OdbcCommand("mysp", cn))
    {
        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("sYear", ddlyear.SelectedValue);

            using (OdbcDataAdapter sda = new OdbcDataAdapter(command))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                gv.DataSource = dt;
                gv.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            command.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**sp**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `mysp`(IN sYear VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN

DECLARE 2sYear VARCHAR(255);
SET 2sYear = sYear;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `mytable_',2sYear,'`;');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

**Edit**

this problem is solved with suggestion of user nbk, there was a copy paste error from the original text
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you variable for the procedure is  `sYear`

But in your code you use `sAnno`

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytable_2025 ( id int)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE  PROCEDURE `mysp`(IN sYear VARCHAR(255))
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE 2sYear VARCHAR(255);
> SET 2sYear = sYear;
>
> SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `mytable_',2sYear,'`;');
> PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>
> END
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> call mysp('2025')
> ```
>
> ```
> | id |
> | -: |
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @s
> ```
>
> ```
> | @s                            |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | SELECT * FROM `mytable_2025`; |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @2sYear
> ```
>
> ```
> | @2sYear |
> | :------ |
> | null    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f38cbf3f070858fdd4783e41acf010e)*